# How to make vue 3 silent?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I wish to disable all Vue 3 logs and warnings.

What is the equivalent in Vue 3 to:

```
Vue.config.silent = true
```

[Documentation for Vue2 silent config](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems it's been removed in Vue3 but I can't find any reference to it in the docs.

The config has custom error/warning handlers which you could use to return `null` instead:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({});

app.config.errorHandler = () => null;
app.config.warnHandler = () => null;

app.mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app">{{ anError.value }}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `devServer` field inside your `vue.config.js` configuration file with an object with the following entry:

```
{
    clientLogLevel: 'silent',
}
```

See [this documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver) page and [this one](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverclientloglevel) for details.

Comment: Oddly this didn't appear to have an effect for me although the vue.config.js was clearly applying as I could change the port of the dev server.